# Write/Read Protected memory c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use `VirtualProtectEx()` to change the memory address protection from `PAGE_NOACCESS` to `PAGE_READ_WRITE`, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
#define WIN64_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

char a[16] = {'c','a','m','o','_','0','2','a'};
int b = 33555192;

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

int main() {
        
    if (HWND hWnd = FindWindowA("IW8",0)) {
        
        DWORD oldprotect;
        DWORD pID = 0;
        
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pID);

        HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pID);

        uint64_t address = 0x7ff6f1ba0d07;

        VirtualQueryEx(pHandle, (LPCVOID)address, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));

        if (VirtualProtectEx(pHandle, (LPVOID)address, 74, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect )) cout << "Changed memory protection !";
        else cout << "Protection changer failed !";
        
        cout << "\n" << "HWND : " << hWnd << "\n" << "PID : " << pID << "\n" << "PHandle : " << pHandle << "\n";

        if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)address, &b, sizeof(b), nullptr)) cout <<  "Found : " << b;
        else (cout << "Invalid address");

        cout << "\n\nMbi : " << mbi.Protect;

        CloseHandle(pHandle);
    }
    else cout << "Process not found !";

    int abc;
    cin >> abc; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror ?

Comment: @IłyaBursov That's amusing (and also good advice).  OP, where did the value you're using for `address` come from?

Comment: You are not doing adequate error handling. Assuming `FindWindowA()` is not returning NULL - does `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` succeed? Does `OpenProcess()` succeed? Does `VirtualQueryEx()` succeed?  I'm betting `OpenProces()` is failing.  `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is simply too many permissions to ask for just to use `VirtualQueryEx()` and `VirtualProtectEx()`.  Though, why are you changing the protection of 74 bytes (why 74?) just to read 4 bytes? And why are you using `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` instead of `PAGE_READONLY`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am printing everything and it is retturning a pHandle so I guess openprocess is working
and i am using readwrite bcs i am using readprocess now but I might need to change it to Write later
And I got that address from Cheat Engine and HxD

Answer (score 0):

Please note that PAGE_NO_ACCESS can also mean that **The page is not allocated** which means that `VirtualProtectEx` will fail no matter what. You can try to use `VirtualAllocEx` to try to **Allocate** some memory at the location `0x7ff6f1ba0d07` first preferably with MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE and PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE before trying using `VirtualProtectEx`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex

Comment: How is it not allocated if there is an Hex stored on that address ?

Comment: @PolyMorph How did you know there is a hex value is stored in that address, if you have no access to it?